# How to realize binomial test in R using data?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, descriptive-statistics

I should do test these data using binomial test (2 first tasks). I have no idea how to do this! I will appreciate any help or mind-joggers!
         [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance a binomial test tests the null hypothesis

$$H_0: \text{Juror's choose lower and higher with equal probability}$$

This corresponds to the case where p = 1/2 for Chose Lower and Chose Higher. To test this in r, look at the `binom.test(...)` function.

Docs: http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/stats/html/binom.test.html

Example:

```
data <- c(150, 50)
names(data) <- c('Chose Higher', 'Chose Lower')
binom.test(data, n = 200, p = 1/2)
```

Output:

```
    Exact binomial test

    data:  data
    number of successes = 150, number of trials = 200, p-value = 8.393e-13
    alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
    95 percent confidence interval:
     0.6840372 0.8083928
    sample estimates:
    probability of success 
              0.75
```

Our low p-value tells us we should reject the null hypothesis and accept the alternative which is that people are more likely to select one class over the other.

For the neighboring level test you would instead compare those who chose 1 level higher or lower vs those that chose 2 or 3 in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks so much for your notes! I have some difficulties with this task because I cannot understand how I should operate this data to make binomial test. In third point within this task I should make chi-square test, so I am in maze with it.

Comment: Hi @Blake, welcome to CV. Please read our [help/on-topic] on homework-style questions; specifically the part relating to hints and guidance.